# How to convert float to int by dropping "0" and ","?

Tags: python

I have a float variable with a value of 0.9533. How can I convert it to an int variable so that the value becomes 9553?

```py
a = ((i.left + i.right) / 2)
a = ("{:.4f}".format(a)) //get a: float = 0.9533
print(f"Result 1: {a}")
b = int(a * 10000) //get b: int
print(f"Result 2: {b}")
```

I get an error:

```
Result 1: 0.9533
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.95330.95330...95330'
```

Comment: Remove `a = ("{:.4f}".format(a))`, then use `int(a * 10000)`.

Comment: What if the number is .25, or .0004251 or .123456?

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```py
a: float = 0.9533 # Get the number here.
b: int = int(str(a).split('.')[1])
```

This converts the `float` to a `string`, then uses Python's [`split`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) method for `string` to split it by the '.' character, then gets the second element of the returned array (index 1), and converts that back into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general solution that will work with any number.

```py
import decimal

def to_int(num):
  d = decimal.Decimal(str(num))
  exponent = d.as_tuple().exponent * -1
  return int(num * (10 ** (exponent)))

to_int(0.9553) # 9553
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, the number was 0.953381023.. . It was necessary to round to 4 digits after the dot, so I used formatting.

This solution helped me:

```
b = int((a * 10000)[2:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = .0004251
b,c = map(str,map(int,str(a).split('.',1)))
print(int(b+c))
```

Output:

```
4251
```